# Eclipse file browser started displaying weird list of files out of nowhere

Tags: eclipse, debugging

In every project folder of mine, there's this huge list of files that make no sense for being there. They only showed up today and I haven't done anything out of the ordinary to trigger this reaction. Can I make them go away??
[image: picture of files]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? What does the `.classpath` file in the project contain?

Comment: That list would normally be under the "JRE System Library" entry for the project

Comment: @nitind Probably going to delete this post. Found out that I had opened the wrong java perspective entirely, my apologies